# I have an SQL syntax error when inputing data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm getting a problem that I cannot seem to overcome. I predict it's a small syntax error but I don't know.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
<?php
$x=$_POST['firstname'];
$y=$_POST['lastname'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="db1";
//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'user' ('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('$x','$y')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created succesfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Once I press submit to input the data the following error comes up:

Connected successfullyError: INSERT INTO 'user' ('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('rty','rty')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' ('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('rty','rty')' at line 1

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your query replace single quote(') from table name and column name with (`), Like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`fname`, `lname`) VALUES ('$x','$y')";
```